# C# greater than or equal to of a value from Console.Readline

Tags: c#

This is my code. I don't understand why it doesn't work. I've tried looking into it but haven't found out why. Do I need to use bool instead? (I'm very new to programming altogether)
Thanks, Jared

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name; 
            Console.WriteLine("Hi. Whats your name?");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} my name is John", name);
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you {0}?", name);
            string age = Console.ReadLine();
            if (age >= 35)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are getting old");
            }
            else if (age <= 35)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are still young");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thats not an option!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify _what_ does not work? Does it crash? Does it return the wrong value?

Comment: Lets say someone enters 'foo' as `age`, how do you intend on comparing that to 35?

Comment: Your code will report someone who is 35 as an _old fart_ whereas you seem to want to report them as _"young"_ too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int age = 0;
var result = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age);

if (result)
{

  if (age >= 35)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("You are getting old");
  }
  else if (age <= 35)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("You are still young");
  }
  else
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Thats not an option!");
   }
}
```

Before converting the inputed age into string you must check that your entry is a number, so you can use [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When you read the input via `Console.ReadLine()` it returns a `string`
When you try a comparison afterwards you are comparing a string to an integer.
You need first to convert the string to an integer.
If you want to make it stable and catch wrong inputs you could put in a try/catch block:

```
string age = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    int ageInInt = Convert.ToInt16(age);
    if (ageInInt >= 35)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You are getting old");
    }
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type a real number");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

out put of `console.readline()` is string you are checking equality with integer

```
            int convertedage = Convert.ToInt(age);
            if (convertedage >= 35)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are getting old");
            }
```

Comment: He said he's new to programming, so I wouldn't recommend him this - could failed. TryParse or use this construction in try/catch would be better idea.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine` returns a `string` value and you are comparing a `string` with `int` you need to parse the value to `int`

```
int age = 0 ;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age)
{
if (age >= 35)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("You are getting old");
  }
  else if (age <= 35)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("You are still young");
  }
  else
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Thats not an option!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is because `Console.ReadLine` will return a string and not a integer which you need for your comparison.

Also as a side note, your final else will never be reached as your `else if` will find all the cases that the if didn't. I'm assuming you actually meant the final message for when the user does not enter a number.

You could use the following rewrite, using int.TryParse to convert the input to a number if possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name; 
            Console.WriteLine("Hi. Whats your name?");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} my name is John", name);
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you {0}?", name);
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int age;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out age)) {
              if (age >= 35)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("You are getting old");
              }
              else // else if not needed
              {
                Console.WriteLine("You are still young");
              }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thats not an option!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add additional checks for invalid age ranges (eg -1)

Answer (score 0):

When you write this "string age = Console.ReadLine();" you are storing string type on the left hand side.

If you compare "age" with int (such as age < 35)

or

assign int variable (int number = age;) age must be converted to integer.

Conversions are done by two ways

```
//  First way    
int number = Convert.ToInt32(age);

//  Second way
int number = Int.Parse(age);
```